# Both Oracle and Sybase Kerberos Authentication using Hikari Datasource in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, kerberos, sap-ase, spring-security-kerberos

In my spring boot application I am using two databases Oracle and Sybase and connecting the database using Kerberos. When I kerberised one of them at a time it worked good, but when I try to use both of them at the same time I'm getting an exception.

My datasource for both the database in `.yml` file are as:

```
database:
oracleDatasource:
DriverclassNqme:*oracle Driver*
JdbcUrl: JdbcUrl
data-source-properties:
 oracle.net.kerberos5_cc_name:*location of cache File*
 oracle.net.authentication_services: (KERBEROS5)
 oracle.net.kerberos5_mutual_authentication: true

sybaseDataSource:
driverClassName: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver
jdbcUrl: SyabaseDataBaseUrl
data-source-properties:
 REQUEST_KERBEROS_SESSION: true
 SERVICE_PRINCIPLE_NAME: principlename
```

and I am having one `jass.conf` file for the Sybase

```
com.sun.security.jggs.initiate{
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useTicketCache=true
ticketCache="path of my sybasecache File"
};
```

When I run the my application with below VM argument ,

```
-Djava.security.krb5.conf="path of my conf file"
-Djava.security.auth.login.config="path of my jass.conf file"
-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false
```

at the time I getting the below exception for Oracle datasource

```
Caused by:com.zaxerr.hikari.pool.HikariPool$InitializationException:Failed to initialize the pool:EncryptionKey:Key byte can not be null
```

and when I removed the `-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false` from argument at that time getting the below exception for SybaseDataSource,

```
ERROR IdTableHelper unable to obtain jdbc Connection
java.sql.SQLException:JZ006:caught IOException:java.net.ConnectException:Connection timed out"
```

Can any one help me out how to fix this or how can I use the Kerberos cache file in datasource properties for the Sybase same like Oracle.
Any help suggestion must be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Spring Boot it's really cool (on paper) ... but when you want to do real stuff then it becomes hard ... but not impossible ... a trick for trying to do it correctly is this -> try to avoid all default (or conventional) configuration usage ... for example, avoid using the global java.security.krb5 or the global magic Spring HK pool ... I know it's not easy but research on how to explicitly configure an start Sybase first, then Oracle independently (but without any implicit/default magic) and then combine both ... a tip: try to setup the HK pool and you will have some good clues about it

Comment: Were you able to find any workaround?

Comment: Yes I found one way to connect both the dB at same time

Comment: Would you be able to post your solution as an answer or point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Juan Can you please post your solution?

Comment: I can’t post post the solución, but i ended up using a datasource that lets you set the drive. And I wrote a driver wraper/decorator that calls the Kerberos login before calling getConnection() on the real driver. The Kerberos login is done using jaas clases. It works as a charm. 0 issue.

Comment: And it meres to be a sepárate jaas configuración, lea e the default for oracle.